# Angular Js dropdownlist Ng init not working along with Orderby

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to bind an initial value to the dropdownlist. Here is my code sample

```
$scope.sessionid = $scope.sessions[0];
```

also i want to sort the drop down list which i managed by

```
<select ng-options="session.SessionStartTime for session in sessions | orderBy:'-SessionStartTime' track by session.TrackerSessionId " ng-model="sessionid" >
```

But the initial value is binding before the sorting take place.I need it to take place after sorting...could someone help me sort out this

Comment: You should do your sorting in javascript first then.

Comment: sort the array right before assigning the initial value

Comment: Yeah ..i tried that but since i am using JSON data to populate the field, i didnt really know how to sort a particular object of thewhole JSON by angular js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a native javascript sort of your array of objects. You can change the sort direction by swapping the `>` and `<` operators. You can then remove the `orderBy` filter.

```
$scope.sessions.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a.SessionStartTime < b.SessionStartTime) return -1;
  if (a.SessionStartTime > b.SessionStartTime) return 1;
  return 0;
});

$scope.sessionid = $scope.sessions[0];
```